# How can I pass the output of the command to variable while in SSH remote session?

Tags: variables, ksh, aix

I am trying to store the output of a command executed via SSH remote session into a variable, but it seems I got some errors. Here is my code:

my_function () {

```
ssh 'user'@$1 <<-END_SSH 2>/dev/null

var=`grep STRING $file.txt | cut -d"'" -f2 | cut -d"(" -f1`

echo "$var"
```

END_SSH

}

And here is the error:

grep: 0652-033 Cannot open file.txt.

If I execute only the command "grep STRING $file.txt | cut -d"'" -f2 | cut -d"(" -f1" without assigning to $var, everything is successful.

Can you please help me with this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ` and $ characters are probably being interpreted by the local shell, try escaping them with \

Comment: Thanks for your help! I modified the code as following:

ref_conn=\$(grep CONNAME $new_node_id.mqsc | cut -d"'" -f2 | cut -d"(" -f1)

Now it`s working!

Comment: If there`s any way to rate your comment, please let me know. I'm just new to the forum and I don't know the procedures. Thanks again!